# VB.Net Cast string larger than 6 characters to timespan. For example hhhhh:mm:ss

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I am getting an integer string. It could be 512 or it could be  15215534. The first one would be 5 min. 12 seconds. The 2nd number would be 1521 hours, 55 minutes, and 34 seconds. This is what I am using now:

```
Dim input As String
Dim time As TimeSpan
Dim length As Integer
length = input.Length

'Return 0 if null
If length = 0 Then
    result = 0
    Return result
End If

time = New TimeSpan(0, input.Substring(0, length - 4), input.Substring(length - 4, 2), input.Substring(length - 2, 2), 0)
```

The code now errors for inputs with 4 character lengths or smaller. Is my best solution to use if statements for the different lengths or is there a better, built in way to do this?

Comment: Easiest would probably be to just make you input become a seconds value and then do the maths. Everything else will probably end up in some unreadable code.

Comment: Have a look at `TimeSpan.Parse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it as follows:

```
Dim input as String = "2133"
input = input.PadLeft(5, '0')

Dim seconds = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(input.Length - 2, 2))
Dim minutes = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(input.Length - 4, 2))
Dim hours = Convert.ToInt32(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 4))

Dim time = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Basically, you know you'll have at most 2 digits for seconds at the end, the next 2 would be minutes and anything preceding that would be hours.

The challenge would be if you don't have minutes or hours in your string (or even just single seconds) - So, you pad your string with enough `0`s at the start to ensure you won't get any issues and then parse out the numbers you need.

I wrote it in C# and converted it, but I hope it still works.

Comment: OutOfRange Exceptions incoming!

Comment: :) - No problem @Luke, just **hoping** i didn't get it wrong. Of course you'd want extra error-trapping for correct inputs, but this would give the correct start, I'd say.

Comment: Only important is to keep a syntax in the input, as you have explained.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Forget that code John Bustos did the job way better!

---

<s>Easiest would probably be to just make your input become a total seconds value and then do the maths.</s>

If you cant you gotta make sure you have a syntax reading the number from right to left.

```
Dim Number as String = ActualNumber.ToString
Dim Seconds as Integer = 0
If Number.Length = 0 Then GoTo SkipWhatEver

If Number.Length < 3 Then 
    Seconds = CInt(Number)
Else
    Seconds = Cint(Number.Substring(Number.Length-2,2)
End If
Number = Number.Substring(0, Number.Length-2)
Dim Minutes as Integer = 0
```

and so on... lots of code. 
It will get pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes that the input is in TextBox1. It converts the entire string to an integer and then separates the hours, minutes and seconds before creating the Timespan.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num, hhhh, mm, ss As Integer
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text

    If Not Integer.TryParse(input, num) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid time")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ss = num Mod 100
    mm = (num \ 100) Mod 100
    hhhh = num \ 10000

    If ss > 59 Or mm > 59 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid time")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim time As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(hhhh, mm, ss)
End Sub
```

I include checks to make sure that the input is really an integer and that the minutes and seconds are not more than 60.